How to derive OCFS2 Maximum Volume size?
I am newbie of Cluster File System.
Brief
Please let me know why OCFS2's maximum volume is 4 PiB.
Information

Block sizes ranging from 512 bytes to 4 KB, and file-system cluster sizes ranging from 4 KB to 1 MB (both in increments of powers of 2). The maximum supported volume size is 16 TB, which corresponds to a cluster size of 4 KB. A volume size as large as 4 PB is theoretically possible for a cluster size of 1 MB, although this limit has not been tested. 
- A Simple Guide to Oracle Cluster File System (OCFS2) using iSCSI on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure

As Oracle Blog, theoretically maximum volume size could be 4 PiB (with 4KiB Block size, and 1 MiB cluster size)
I found that the definition of "cluster size" is that an amount of file.

A cluster, or file allocation unit size, is the smallest amount of disk space that can hold a file.
Quora, What does cluster size mean when referring to hard drives?

I can guess that, if the system is run in 32-bits system, 4 PiB is right.
* 4 PiB = 2^32 * 2^20B
2^32 bits means the 32 bits system memory address size
2^20 = 1 MiB means maximum cluster size (which means the file minimum unit size).
Question
However, in 2024, there is no 32 bits system in Cluster-level server environment. In those terms, should it be 16 YiB ?
* Equation is 2^64 * 2^20 = 2^84. 1 YiB = 2^80. So, result is 2^4 YiB = 16 YiB.
